# Magento 2 Disabling Custom Module In default store view

Tags: magento2

I have a custom module which i want to use in my second website only and not in deafult website to achieve this i had created system.xml file but it seems like not working and the module changes are still visible in default website also

**System.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="vendormodule" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>RFQ</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="vendormodule" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Request For Quote</label>
            <tab>vendormodule</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::requestforquote_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Comment: The configuration is show on all store view, but you need to enable it on specific store only.

Comment: but still it works on all stores

Comment: For that you need to code according, so it take value what you set on current store.

Comment: Did you add the check to see if the module is enabled in the required places in the code? if ($this->scopeConfig->getValue('config string', storeConstantString) {...} that type of thing?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya this looks interesting do you know the right approach for this

Comment: Yes, tell me in your code have you check extension is enable or not and if enable then it will show on frontend.

Comment: no i thought it will do the trick using config values based on stores nad yeah even after disabling the module in one store the changes are still visible on frontend and its not working